# ¿Por qué no se visualizan los iconos de las redes sociales?

Tags: html, css

Por favor, ¿me pueden ayudar con esto? Al intenttar mostrar los íconos de las redes sociales en un menú, estos no me aparecen de forma correcta y no sé que es lo que está causando ese error. Para los iconos estoy usando http://fontastic.me/. ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

1. Imagen de mi página web. Deberían aparecer tambien los íconos de las redes sociales
   [image: 1]
2. Referencia para mostrarles como quiero que aparezca la página.
   [image: 2]
3. El index.html

```
<!-- menu -->
<nav class="main-nav" id="nav">
    <!--menu container -->
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class=main-menu__link>Home</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class=main-menu__link>About</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class=main-menu__link>Events</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class=main-menu__link>Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class=main-menu__link>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Redes sociales (es la parte que no se muestra bien)-->
    <div class="social-networks">
        <a class="icon-facebook social-networks__item" href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
        <a class="icon-twitter social-networks__item" href="https://www.twitter.com"></a>
        <a class="icon-youtube social-networks__item" href="https://www.youtube.com"></a>
        <a class="icon-linkedin social-networks__item" href="https://www.linkedin.com"></a>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- banner -->
<div class="main-banner">
    <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Banner" class="main-banner__img">
    <!-- Datos -->
    <div class="main-banner__data">
        <!-- titulo -->
        <h2 class="main-banner__title">Go Greem</h2>
        <!-- subtitulo -->
        <p class="main-banner__subtitle>Save the world by planting trees</p>
        <!-- descripcion -->
        <p class="main-banner__descripcion>Lorep isum sit amet...</p>
        <!-- botones -->
        <a href="" class="main-banner__button button button--light">Join now</a> 
        <a href="" class="main-banner__button button button--cta">Donate now</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

4. El CSS usando Sass

```
.main-menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    &__item{
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(#fff,0.5);
    }

    &__link{
        display:block;
        line-height: 3;
        padding: 0 1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
}

.social-networks{
    padding-left: 1em;

    &__item{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 3;
        margin-right: 2em;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: estas utilizando alguna librería como [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/?from=io)? o de que manera quieres agregar el icono?, solo veo la clase `icon-facebook` pero deverias de poner que estas utilizando como icono

Comment: holaaa, bueno estoy usando Fontastic, donde solo se necesita el enlace y escribir el nombre de los icons

Comment: Realmente no tengo experiencia usando *Fontastic* pero [aquí](http://fontastic.me/howto) viene como usarlo, En mi experiencia te recomiendo [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) es mas sencillo.

Comment: [Como usar FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) y [Lista de Iconos](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

Comment: Yo uso fontello, Además de la clase icon-facebook, debes agregar la clase icon, o algo por el estilo

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema debe ser que la nube donde se guarda los iconos no este funcionando perfectamente, pero si los descargas y los enlazas, luego te aparecen normal

Comment: Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta, lee [answer]

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar el código en lugar de capturas de pantalla por favor?

Comment: Agrega el código completo del index.html, de forma que se vean los tag `<link>`, a ver si es un problema de cómo estás referenciando a FontAwesome.

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de estar utilizando codigo que te provee Fontastic cuando le das a `Publish` luego de selecionar los iconos que quieres.

[imagen de ejemplo del codigo que te provee](https://i.gyazo.com/4bee939b5dbb545051829acb74ab5dd1.png)

Copias y pegas ese codigo que te da Fontastic en el `head` de tu pagina.

También asegurate de usar las clases que te dice Fontastic, deben estar debajo en la sección `Icons Reference`

Answer (score 1):

debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente *Fontastic* te permite descargar un codigo que debes incluir en tu servidor web. asi mismo, como mencionas son diseños propios, por lo cual debes importarlos y luego importar desde el sitio... este descargara un archivo zip el cual debe colocarlo en la raíz del sitio para empezar, no se si pertenecen a *Fontastic* si funciona todo esta correcto solo debes escribir el código bien.

Ejemplo: en el [div](/questions/tagged/div) la [class](/questions/tagged/class) incluye el elemento icon [space](/questions/tagged/space) luego el nombre del [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) por lo general la frace [icon](/questions/tagged/icon) esta presente antes del nombre

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li> 
        <div class="icon main-menu__item"></div>
                <a href="#" class="main-menu__link" value="adn">home</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <div class="icon main-menu__item"></div>
                <a href="#" class="main-menu__link" value="adn">about us</a>
            </li>
        <li>
                <div class="icon main-menu__item"></div>
                <a href="#" class="main-menu__link" value="adn">Events</a>
            </li>
        <li>
                <div class="icon main-menu__item"></div>
                <a href="#" class="main-menu__link" value="adn">Gallery</a>
            </li>
        <li>
                <div class="icon main-menu__item"></div>
                <a href="#" class="main-menu__link" value="adn">Contact</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

por otra parte debes revisar los nombre que tienen los iconos personalizados sean los mismos que coloco al archivo, y el link que proporciono ***fontastic*** ejemplo:

```
<link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/waEYfjQBZE8EYyaXxeTuMb/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

en otro orden de ideas, recomiendo que si descargo el archivo este incluye un ejemplo, bastante explicativo de como funciona, recomiendo checkear dicho archivo le aseguro que saldrá de dudas rapidamente con toda esta explicación

Answer (score 1):

El problema podría ser la falta del link a los estilos en tu **HEAD**. 
Tendrías que agregar algo así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mfglabs_iconset.css">
```

En el **HREF** es necesario poner la ubicación del archivo o la dirección en la nube.